# Have Jenkins trigger GitlabCI

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

Assuming a user initiates a Jenkins job, passing some input parameters.

Is there a way, at some point to have the Jenkins job trigger a `gitlab-ci`, **and** also pass to it (i.e. the `gitlab` pipeline) some input parameters which the latter will use as environment variables?

Comment: That sounds uterly strange to chain two CI systems... what's the point ?

Comment: Cannot find a way to provide user input for manual pipeline triggering in gitlab (where a lot of my infrastructure lies right now).

Comment: That sounds an XY problem (as adding jenkins is already a try to solution the real problem) but I assume this could help: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/jobs.html

Answer (score 2):

Note: I didn't use this yet, the answer is based solely on documentation.

A GitlabCI pipeline can be triggered via API, see [Triggering pipelines through the API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/triggers/).

> Triggers can be used to force a pipeline rerun of a specific `ref` (branch or tag) with an API call.

You would first need to [create a trigger](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/triggers/#adding-a-new-trigger) for that pipeline.

Then you can [activate that trigger](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/triggers/#triggering-a-pipeline) (from your jenkins job in this case):

> To trigger a job you need to send a `POST` request to GitLab's API
>   endpoint:
>
> ```
> POST /projects/:id/trigger/pipeline
> ```
>
> The required parameters are the [trigger's `token`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/triggers/#authentication-tokens) and the Git
>   `ref` on which the trigger will be performed. Valid refs are the
>   branch and the tag.

Such triggers support [variable passing](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/triggers/#making-use-of-trigger-variables):

> You can pass any number of arbitrary variables in the trigger API call
>   and they will be available in GitLab CI so that they can be used in
>   your `.gitlab-ci.yml` file. The parameter is of the form:
>
> ```
> variables[key]=value
> ```

You can use the variables inside `.gitlab-ci.yml` like this:

> ```
> upload_package:
>   stage: package
>   script:
>   - if [ -n "${UPLOAD_TO_S3}" ]; then make upload; fi
> ```

And

> You can then trigger a rebuild while you pass the `UPLOAD_TO_S3`
>   variable and the script of the `upload_package` job will run:
>
> ```
> curl --request POST \
>   --form token=TOKEN \
>   --form ref=master \
>   --form "variables[UPLOAD_TO_S3]=true" \
>   https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/9/trigger/pipeline
> ```

This kind of POST requests is what you would to do in your jenkins job. But take a closer look at the triggers, you might find a way to do what you want without jenkins.